# Using Cordova/Phonegap, why doesn't HTML5 video play in IE11?

Tags: cordova, html5-video

I have a simple html5 video element:

```
<video src="..." style="width:845px;height:635px;" controls></video>
```

The video will display but none of the controls work. They will hide and show on hover but nothing happens when I select play.

Answer (score 0):

Imn't sure but have you tried to use the attribute `webkit-playsinline` on your video tag?

If you work with iOS also try to add `<preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true"/>` in your config.xml

If you work with local video, move your file into SD card or try to update your Android version.

Hope that helped you

Comment: My issue is with a Windows Cordova implementation. IE11, it turns out, works fine. Inside the cordova app the controlls don't work.

Comment: did you try webkit attribute?